# Find elements in doc and email the array via ajax in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery to gather elements on a page then email it over. not sure where I am going wrong. Seems to log correctly... and email php works fine apart from the jQuery.

```
 $('.questionFive').click(function(){
    var name = preSubmit();
    console.log(name);
    var varData = 'name=' + name;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'php.php',
        data: varData,
        success: function(){
            alert("It was a success");
            //window.location.replace("thankyou.html");
        }
    });
 });

function preSubmit(){
    var optionTexts = [];
    $("section").each(function(){
        var h2 = $(this).find("h2").text();
        optionTexts.push(h2);
        optionTexts.push("\n");
        $("ol li", this).each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) })
    });
    var splitText = optionTexts.join("\n");
    console.log(splitText)
    var fromWho = "from: Company Name"
    splitText += fromWho;
    return splitText;
}
```

php file:

```
<?php
        $subject = "survey";
        $email = "lukasz@visualhero.com";
        $message = $_POST["name"];

        mail($email, $subject, $message);
?>
```

Comment: Try `data: {name: name }` instead of `data: varData`, it might have to do with encoding the request param

Answer (score 0):

What actually is your problem? I can see only this:

```
var varData = 'name=' + name;
...
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'php.php',
        data: varData,
        success: function(){
```

and

```
$message = $_POST["name"];
```

looks weird to me. Try the following:

```
var varData = { 'name': encodeURIComponent(name) };
....
       data: varData,
       ...
```

This will format a proper json object with a property "name" which then can retrieved from the $_POST array. Besides: "name" as the name for a variable causes problems on certain Browsers since "name" is a reserved word.

Comment: it just wont send the form. I seems like everything is correct though, so I am confused. I will try replacing name (but I know I have gotten similar things working in chrome using name)